# Difficulties in understanding Python code that computes transformed mesh

Tags: python, numpy, graphics

There's some code that I have basically translated from its [original version in MATLAB](http://gvvperfcapeva.mpi-inf.mpg.de/public/ScanDB/data/relrot.tar.gz) to Python but there is a part that I don't understand. I have one triangle mesh that I want to transform. For this, the transformations for each triangle face is computed. After that, the edges of the transformed triangle are specified. However, what happens then is unclear to me. If you have any mathematical or geometric background to share concerning the following steps, I would appreciate it very much!

```
weight = np.ones(1)

fixvertex = 1
fixto = np.zeros((3))

M = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix((len(template) + fixvertex, len(template)))
dx = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix((len(template) + fixvertex, 3))
for i in range(len(faces)):
    v = faces[i, :]
    ### ... what happens inbetween is irrelevant
    # Transform triangle
    x = T @ np.array([template[v[0], :], template[v[1], :], template[v[2], :]]).reshape(3, 3).T

    p12 = x[:, 0] - x[:, 1]
    p13 = x[:, 0] - x[:, 2]
    p23 = x[:, 1] - x[:, 2]

    p12 = p12 / np.linalg.norm(p12)
    p13 = p13 / np.linalg.norm(p13)
    p23 = p23 / np.linalg.norm(p23)

    # I do not get the point of the following lines

    wts = [(p13.T).dot(p23), -(p12.T).dot(p23), (p12.T).dot(p13)]
    wij3 = [[0, wts[0] / np.sqrt(1 - wts[0] ** 2), wts[1] / np.sqrt(1 - wts[1] ** 2)],
            [0, 0, wts[2] / np.sqrt(1 - wts[2] ** 2)],
            [0, 0, 0]]
    wij3 = np.asarray(wij3)
    wij3 = wij3 + wij3.T
    WIJ = wij3 - np.diag([sum(x) for x in zip(*wij3)])
    M[np.ix_(v, v)] = M[np.ix_(v, v)] + WIJ
    dx[v, :] = dx[v, :] + (WIJ @ x.T)

weight = np.ones((fixvertex)) * weight

for i in range(fixvertex):
    M[len(template) + i, fixvertex - 1] = weight[i]

dx[len(template):len(template) + fixvertex, :] = np.multiply(fixto, np.tile(weight, (3)))

M = np.real(M)
dx = np.real(dx)
Mt = M.T

model = scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(Mt @ M, Mt @ dx)
```

Comment: We can't run you code without some input arrays like `faces` and `template`.  And even with that I'm not sure I'd want to.  How did you get those lines you don't understand?  Did you just mechanically translate some block of MATLAB code?  Knowing that code might help, but even then I'd have to understand the larger context.  That's not something I can do in 15 minutes (my attention span for topics like this).